# Which video/movie file format would be most convenient for inclusion into a Keynote or PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: video, ms-office, keynote, quicktime, movie

I am a Windows user, and I have never used Keynote or PowerPoint on Mac. My colleague would like me to send him a video/movie file that he can incorporate into and play during a scientific presentation. He will use either Keynote or PowerPoint for Mac to create the presentation.

Which file format would be most convienent for inclusion into Keynote *and/or*  PowerPoint for Mac presentations?  Some file formats that I can create on Windows include:

- ***.avi**
- ***.mov** (QuickTime)
- ***.mpg**
- ***.mpeg**

On Windows, I have found it very difficult to successfully include videos/movies in PowerPoint presentations; usually the slideshow ends up crashing or the video stalls. I am hoping that the Apple developers have this perfected in Keynote and PowerPoint for Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested AVI, MOV, and MP4 in Keynote and PowerPoint for Mac.  All three work fine in both applications.